# Python: Convert image from RGB to YDbDr color space

Tags: python, image, opencv, rgb

Trying to convert image from RGB color space to YDbDr color space according to the formula:

```
Y = 0.299R + 0.587G + 0.114B

Db = -0.45R - 0.883G +1.333B

Dr = -1.333R + 1.116G + 0.217B
```

With the following code I'm trying to show only Y channel which should be grayscale image but I keep getting image all in blue color:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread("./pics/Slike_modela/Test/Proba/1_Color.png")
new_img = []
for row in img:
    new_row = []
    for pixel in row:
        Y = 0.299*pixel[2]+0.587*pixel[1]+0.114*pixel[0]
        Db = -0.45*pixel[2]-0.883*pixel[1]+1.333*pixel[0]
        Dr = -1.333*pixel[2]+1.116*pixel[1]+0.217*pixel[0]
        new_pixel = [Y, Db, Dr]
        new_row.append(new_pixel)
    new_img.append(new_row)

new_img_arr = np.array(new_img)
new_img_arr_y = new_img_arr.copy()
new_img_arr_y[:,:,1] = 0
new_img_arr_y[:,:,2] = 0
print (new_img_arr_y)
cv2.imshow("y image", new_img_arr_y) 
key = cv2.waitKey(0)
```

When printing the result array I see correct numbers according to formula and correct shape of the array.

What is my mistake? How to get Y channel image i.e. grayscale image?

Comment: If you want greyscale, you should use `new_pixel = [Y, Y, Y]`: all values should be the same.

Comment: Can You explain why? I tried with all three Y and it is still the same.
When I try with RGB image I can easily show only one channel, for example red channel by simply setting blue and green values of the pixel to 0.

Comment: If you set all Y, you should remove the setting of zero on the other bytes. Greyscale means that all colours should have the same intensity (black and white have both the same intensities).

Comment: Can you tell me which color is [255,0,0] in BGR? What happens if you have G,R channels set to 0? Either make a single channel image, or set the three channel to the same value

Comment: You were right, with setting all three channels of pixel to Y it was showing grayscale. Although at first, it was showing white image that was solved with modification: 
cv2.imshow("image y", np.uint8(new_img_arr_y)).


[255,0,0] with G and R set to 0 is pure blue image.


Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

When processing images with Python, you really, really should try to avoid:

- treating images as lists and appending millions and millions of pixels, each of which creates a whole new object and takes space to administer
- processing images with `for` loops, which are very slow

The better way to deal with both of these is through using `Numpy` or other vectorised code libraries or techniques. That is why **OpenCV**, `wand`, `scikit-image` open and handle images as Numpy arrays.

So, you basically want to do a dot product of the colour channels with a set of 3 weights:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image
im = cv2.imread('paddington.png', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

# Calculate Y using Numpy "dot()"
Y = np.dot(im[...,:3], [0.114, 0.587, 0.299]).astype(np.uint8)
```

That's it.

[image]